# Terraform conditionally create resource based on variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a Terraform module that will create an AWS Elastic IP and attach it to the specific EC2 instance that has the **elastic_ip** variable set to **true**.

***instances.tfvars***

```
aws_ec2_instances = {
  instance-1 = {
    ami_id        = $AMI_ID
    instance_type = "c5.large"
    key_pair      = "ssh-key"
    subnet_id     = $SUBNET_ID
    sg_ids        = $SG_IDS
    disk_size     = "100"
    elastic_ip    = true
  }
  instance-2 = {
    ami_id        = $AMI_ID
    instance_type = "c5.large"
    key_pair      = "ssh-key"
    subnet_id     = $SUBNET_ID
    sg_ids        = $SG_IDS
    disk_size     = "100"
    elastic_ip    = false
  }
  instance-3 = {
    ami_id        = $AMI_ID
    instance_type = "c5.large"
    key_pair      = "ssh-key"
    subnet_id     = $SUBNET_ID
    sg_ids        = $SG_IDS
    disk_size     = "100"
    elastic_ip    = true
  }
}
```

So far I have the following code. This code works well for X instances that have `elastic_ip = false` and 1 instance that has `elastic_ip = true`. The moment I try to add more instances with `elastic_ip = true` the code tries to create and attach multiple eips for each of the instances and it doesn't work properly.

***main.tf***

```
data "aws_instance" "ec2_instances_with_eips" {
  for_each       = { for k in compact([for k, v in var.aws_ec2_instances : v.elastic_ip == true ? k : ""]): k => var.aws_ec2_instances[k] }
    
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = [each.key]
  }
}
    
resource "aws_eip" "eips" {
  for_each       = { for k in compact([for k, v in var.aws_ec2_instances : v.elastic_ip == true ? k : ""]): k => var.aws_ec2_instances[k] }
   domain         = "vpc"
   instance       = data.aws_instance.ec2_instances_with_eips[each.key].id
    
   tags = {
     Name         = format("%s-%s",each.key,"eip")
   }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this to work for multiple instances ?

**P.S:** The module that creates the EC2 instances is separate from the module that creates and attaches the elastic IPs.

Comment: Well, you could say in the EIP resource something like: `for_each = data.aws_instance.ec2_instances_with_eips`. Then, in the `instance` argument you would use `each.value.id`. That might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on some local tests, I think this should work:

```
data "aws_instance" "ec2_instances_with_eips" {
  for_each = { for k, v in var.aws_ec2_instances : k => v if v.elastic_ip }

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = [each.key]
  }
}

resource "aws_eip" "eips" {
  for_each = data.aws_instance.ec2_instances_with_eips
  instance = each.value.id

  tags = {
    Name = format("%s-%s", each.key, "eip")
  }
}
```

As you can see, the first `for_each` is using only the variable without any additional work required. Also, the `for_each` will select only keys whose values for `elastic_ip` are equal to `true` (denoted with `k => v if v.elastic_ip`). The `for_each` in the `aws_eip` resource is using the `for_each` [chaining between resources](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#chaining-for_each-between-resources).

Comment: Hmm, I just tested it. It seems my code works as well. What I was afraid of is that terraform will mess up my already existing instances - whenever I tried to add a new instance, `terraform plan` was reporting that it will `# module.aws_eip.data.aws_instance.ec2_instances_with_eips["instance-X"] will be read during apply` and `# module.aws_eip.aws_eip.eips["instance-X"] will be updated in-place`. However, I ran `terraform apply` and it seems it doesn't mess with the already created instances, which is nice.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The remaining question is - Do you think your code is better than mine ? I am not an expert on Terraform so I cannot make a decision on whether to change my code.

Comment: Any code that works is great. :) I just tend to simplify things and make them more readable. It's up to you to choose what you will use. :)